# mongoose return null in the query

Tags: node.js, mongoose

my mongodb has a collection with data like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62ead2a8dd6922cfd6f466e4"),
    "t" : "d",
    "u" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("621d3469dd01e282b9a62321"),
        "username" : "helxsz"
    },
    "users" : [ 
        ObjectId("621d3469dd01e282b9a62321"), 
        ObjectId("628ee99ed0a58e00496a0730")
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-08-03T19:55:20.965Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-08-03T19:55:20.965Z")
}
```

I am using node.js and mongoose to query the document.

```
  let query = {
    u:{
      _id: "621d3469dd01e282b9a62321",
      username: "helxsz"
   },
   t:'d',
  };
      collection
        .findOne(query, 'u t ')
        .exec(getResult);
```

why the executed query returns null to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe is because in your DB the `u._id` is `ObjectId` and in your query is a string. Mongoose should (?) parse it but I've faced not-parsed error like this many times.

So try parsing to `ObjectId`, in [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sk-mTnZX-m8) works.

Also an other problem is trying to search an object like this:

```
{
  u:{
    _id: "621d3469dd01e282b9a62321",
    username: "helxsz"
  }
}
```

Because in this way mongo looks for by the objects with the same order. You have to use [dot notation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)

As an example, check how [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rG1Jcv2xk9S) not work all times. To ensure the result you have to use dot notation:

```
let query = {
  "u._id": "621d3469dd01e282b9a62321", // maybe casting to ObjectId is necessary
  "u.username": "helxsz",
  t: "d"
}
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NfK3r_VAmqv)

More info about [Match an Embedded/Nested Document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#match-an-embedded-nested-document)